# How can I make the loop() execute exactly once in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

How can I prevent the code to print output twice? The loop() in Arduino is runnin twice despite using exit(0). How can I prevent that? While(1) also didn't work. Input has to be hardcoded. No input through serial is permitted.

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial s(10,11);

int roll_num =123, roll[10], i=0, r, j; 
char x;

void setup()
{
       s.begin(9600); 
       Serial.begin(9600); //Opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps.
       //Serial.println("Enter roll number");
       //int roll_num; 
       
}    

void loop()
{
       //if (Serial.available()>0)
       //{
           //x=Serial.read(); // Reads the incoming byte.
           //roll_num = x - '0';
           while (roll_num != 0) 
           {
                //Extracts the last digit of roll number
                r = roll_num % 10;
  
                //Puts the digit in roll[]
                roll[i] = r;
                i++;
  
                //Updates roll_num to roll_num/10 to extract next last digit
                roll_num = roll_num / 10;
           }

           for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--)
           {
                Serial.print("sent number: ");
                Serial.println(roll[j]);
                s.write(roll[j]); //Writes a binary digit of the roll number to the serial port.
           }
      //}
      delay(100);
      exit(0); 
      //while(1);
}
```

Output:

```
sent number: 1
sent number: 2
sent number: 3
sent number: 1
sent number: 2
sent number: 3
```

Comment: You don't need to put your code in the loop() if you only want to execute the code once. Put it in the setup().

Comment: Did. Problem persists.

Comment: the Serial Monitor does a reset. the first run is the buffered input from the run after upload, the second run is after reset by Serial Monitor. print something in setup() and you will see that twice too

Comment: Is there a way to overcome that?

Comment: is it a problem that it resets twice?

Comment: yeah because those values will be sent to a nodeMCU controller which will be doing some computations with them. If values are sent twice Nodemcu will be wrongly adding the values twice.

Comment: but then there will be no reset by upload and no reset by Serial Monitor

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem using a Duemilanove. The loop runs once, as expected. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to execute the contents of `loop()` could be to wrap it in a conditional statement and create a global boolean that is offset at the end of the first loop.

```c
bool firstLoop = true;
void loop()
{
    if (firstLoop){
        doThisOnce();
        firstLoop = false;
    }
}

void doThisOnce()
{ 
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In arduino the code dont execute in a linear way, it goes in a loop way. When starting the program the part of the `void setup()` will execute only once, but the part of the `void loop()` will execute indefinite. To be able to execute the program only once you should put all the code that you want to execute only once in `void setup()`

Hope it helps!